# Solving index out of range error

Tags: c#

I am using gridview row commands edit and delete. When I click on those links that particular row data shows on textboxes as mentioned.

First loop is working but for `e.CommandName == "deletevalue"` showing an error

> index was out of range. must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

```
protected void GrdBuilding_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
        if (e.CommandName == "editvalue")
        {

            TxtBuildingid.Text = GrdBuilding.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
            TxtBuildingCode.Text = GrdBuilding.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
            TxtBuildingName.Text = GrdBuilding.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;
            DrpBuilding.Text = GrdBuilding.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text;
            if (GrdBuilding.Rows[index].Cells[5].Text.ToString() == "True")
            {
                ChkisActive.Checked = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ChkisActive.Checked = false;
            }

            BtnSave.Text = "Update";
        }



        else if (e.CommandName == "deletevalue")
        {
            TxtBuildingid.Text = GrdBuilding.Rows[index].Cells[1].Text;
            TxtBuildingCode.Text = GrdBuilding.Rows[index].Cells[2].Text;
            TxtBuildingName.Text = GrdBuilding.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text;
            DrpBuilding.Text = GrdBuilding.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text;
            if (GrdBuilding.Rows[index].Cells[5].ToString() == "True")
            {
                ChkisActive.Checked = true;
            }
            else
                ChkisActive.Checked = false;
            }

            BtnSave.Text = "Delete";
        }
```

Comment: Nothing about `e.CommandName == "deletevalue"` will throw an index out of range exception (if you want to be technical it can but let's not be nitpicky about this assumption). What's the exact line inside that block that throws the error?

Comment: By the way you are missing an opening brace in your `else` block...

Comment: check index like this GrdBuilding.Rows.Count >= index before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't answer this question in terms of "do this, then it will work", because the problem is not in the code you show us.

I will try to answer in terms of what you can do to find the problem.

**You need to debug your code.** This is a basic procedure and when I read your question, it seems to me, that you haven't done it.

1. First step for me would be to set a break point on the `else if` row in your IDE.
2. When the execution stops there, check the value of `e.CommandArgument`

   ==> Is it wrong or undefined?
3. Now, go back to where `GrdBuilding_RowCommand(...)` has been called. Where does `e.CommandArgument` comes from? There has to be a problem in the logic on how you have set the value.

There you will either find the problem, of find another point in the code where something happens that is not clear to you. Set a new break point there and step through your code, watch the process of creating `e.CommandArgument`.

Comment: i got the result.....i didnt call CommandArgument for linkbutton delete ....thanks for ur precious replies folks;)